# Custom Login page with User name and Password as Input.Password Input field have have some icon in that which will show or hide the Password

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Lightning input password or UI:inputSecret component having   eye icon  to show or hide password logic with caps Lock functionality .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need to built custom login page with user name and password.Password input field should have eye icon to show or hide the password

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for this but you can use Lightning Design System to create this component. You need to use `slds-form-element` and combine two base components `lightning:input` and `lightning:buttonIcon` to create the Inpute element with eye Icon. With the help of JS controller you can toggle the type of the Input element betwwen text and password. Also change the Icon from Hide to Show and vice versa.

*Aura Component*

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="password" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="showpassword" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-around_large">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="password_field">Password</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
            <lightning:input variant = "label-hidden" type="{!v.showpassword ? 'text':'password'}" 
                             aura:id="password_field" value="{!v.password}"/>                                    
            <lightning:buttonIcon class="slds-button slds-input__icon slds-text-color--default" 
                                  iconName="{!v.showpassword ? 'utility:hide':'utility:preview'}" 
                                  alternativeText="{!v.coborrowerSSNCB ? 'Hide':'Show'}" 
                                  onclick="{!c.togglePassword}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

*JS Controller*

```
({
    togglePassword : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(component.get("v.showpassword",true)){
            component.set("v.showpassword",false);
        }else{
            component.set("v.showpassword",true);
        }
    }
})
```

***ScreenShot***

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot let me try

Comment: @BeraSaroj could u plz help me by using ui:inputSecret